# How can I find the region where a complex function has a certain modulus?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have the following complex function

$$
f(z)=\frac{z-1}{z}
$$
and I want to know where $|f(z)|=1$. I'm pretty sure that the answer is $\Re(z)=1/2$ but I don't know how to make this computation.

Thanks in advance